# How to add GUID column in DynamicTableEntity Powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure-table-storage

I am using "DynamicTableEntity" (Powershell) to add columns inside. Below is my sample code-

```
$obj = New-Object "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity" "1", "0"
$obj.Properties.Add("Id", "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")
```

In above code I am adding Id column and I wanted it's datatype to GUID but I am not sure how to define datatypes here.

Can anyone help me out on this?

I tried this-

```
$obj.Properties.Add("Id", EntityProperty.GeneratePropertyForGuid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"))
```

But here I am not getting the "EntityProperty" class.

Comment: try `$obj.Properties.Add("Id", [GUID]::Empty)`

Comment: Try `$entity.Properties.Add("Id", [GUID]"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")`

Comment: @Theo....it works. Thanks.